# Execute a function based on a specific scroll position in React native

Tags: react-native, scrollview

I am trying to call an api base on scroll View current position but not sure how to I achieve that.

This is my code

```
    <ScrollView
           ref={scrollViewRef}
            scrollEventThrottle={0}
            onScroll={({nativeEvent}) => {
              console.log(
                nativeEvent.contentSize.height -
                  nativeEvent.layoutMeasurement.height,
              );
              console.log(nativeEvent.contentOffset);
            }}>
```

I tried to call the api inside onScroll but that didnt work well.

Comment: Hi , can you please share an example in https://snack.expo.dev/ ?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an event listener at the particular scroll location you want the function to execute.

```
useEffect(() => {
     Window.addEventListener(‘scroll’_.debounce(setScroll,1000));},[]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by using adding an if check. If the api data exist then the function wont execute anymore.
here's the code

```js
const [apiData, setApiData] = useState();

onScroll={({nativeEvent}) => {
          if (!apiData) {
            if (
              nativeEvent.contentSize.height -
                nativeEvent.layoutMeasurement.height -
                nativeEvent.contentOffset.y <
              250
            ) {
              getApiDataHandler();
            }
          }
        }}
```